# I want to Use a "UPI QR Code Payment Gateway" plugin in WordPress at my localhost is it possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, payment-gateway

I was trying to add "**UPI QR Code Payment Gateway**" plugin in my localhost database before i use at my client website but wen i setting up this pulign then that show me "**Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.**" Can any one give the reson for this or **i can use this plugin in my localhost or not?**.trying to find answer in this https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/upi-qr-code-payment-for-woocommerce/ but not able to find.

i was trying to someone give the true answer for my qustion because i need information about that.